# change view of Batch-Generate Preview

Tags: blend-files

Does a way exists to change the view of a batch render preview generated ? according to the documentation, It seems not but I missed maybe something ?

[image]

Especially I would like to change to an Orthographic representation with a different angle.

I'm previewing 2D Elements which are flat